# regex for parsing a img tag in html with parameters

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, backreference

I have this notational language for posting stuff on my blog and I use the following line to parse images

```
$$link_to_image width height alternative_description$$
```

I am parsing this with the following php sentence

```
preg_replace('/\$\$(.*?)\s\d+\s\d+\s(.*?)\$\$/','<img src = "\\1" width = "\\2px" height = "\\3px" alt = "\\4" >',$this->text);
```

where $this->text is the whole text of the blog's post.

the problem is when I enter something like 
`$$http://s15.postimg.org/60dod0gu3/input.png 400 300 Raw data$$` I am getting

```
<img src="http://s15.postimg.org/60dod0gu3/input.png" width="Raw datapx" height="px" alt="">
```

What is wrong with the regex I wrote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only capture 2 groups but you want 4. Add two more capturing groups for the numbers:

```
\$\$(.*?)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.*?)\$\$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR3nY2).